# How do I rename the context root of Application Center in Worklight 6.2?

Tags: worklight-server

I want to rename appcenterconsole to devappcenterconsole, and applicationcenter to devapplicationcenter. I am running Worklight 6.2 on Tomcat. I wonder if this is as simple as rename the war file, deploy it and update the server.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Context container in the Tomcat documentation : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html
Especially the path attribute description. 
You can for example modify the path attributes with : /devappcenterconsole and /devapplicationcenter.

Be aware also that if you modify the default context root of applicationcenter you must configure the endpoint property as documented in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_endpoint_tomcat.html?lang=en